# Hosted Development Server + Git + Bitbucket Workflow

Tags: wordpress, git, version-control, bitbucket

I have just taken over the management of a business-critical WordPress site.

Currently there isn't a development server or any source control. I would therefore like to get this setup and was just after a bit of advice on the best workflow.

Development will be done on one machine initially, but the development server must be hosted so geographically dispersed stakeholders can view the site and sign-off changes before it is deployed to the production server.

I have used Subversion previously, but I would like to make the jump to Git and was thinking about using a private Bitbucket repository.

My questions are:

1. Does this sound like a sensible solution?
2. What is the most efficient/robust method of getting the code from the local machine to the production server (via the development server) while maintaining version control?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do the development initially on your local machine, commit the changes, push them to the bitbucket with Development branch. You can have read only access to your stake holders in order to sign off the changes from Development in the remote to Production in the Remote branch.

Since you used SVN before and trying to migrate to GIT. You can use the `git svn` command to migrate from SVN to GIT.

Or you can use the tool SubGIT tool for a stress free migration from SVN  to GIT.

Comment: Thanks Vamsi,

Is moving things between branches just a Git command?

Also, how would you suggest I deploy from Bitbucket to the development and production servers? I've been reading about DeployBot - Is this something you would recommend?